# How to autocreate a list of instance of a subclass to be able to call the "execute" method on these "scripts" at application startup?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops, class

I have a system where the person using my thingo will be able to create their own scripts. However, I want to make it so that if the user puts `class MyScript : BaseScript`, the script will be added to a list and at the start of the application all scripts derived from "Base Script" will be executed.

Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Comment: sorry mate your post is a little unclear yet. " if the user puts class `MyScript : BaseScript`" puts where? do you have a UI? is the user working in a console? is the user writing code? " the person using my thingo" what is a **thingo** ? " all scripts derived from "Base Script" will be executed" that sounds like you would need reflection to find all the childclasses of `BaseScript` if, of course, you are talking about inheritance here. Please clarify

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for an [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) but I'm not sure, it's pretty unclear actually what you're asking

Comment: Yeah, sorry if it was unclear. I meant that is the person using this (what I would call an API), would be writing the code, and they would use `class MyScript : BaseScript` if they wanted their script(s) to execute at the start of the program. They would be using inheritance, as the BaseScript class contains stuff like `public virtual void Start()` and `public virtual void Update()`. However keep in mind this script will not be instanced at any time, as that would require manually adding it to the `main()` part of the program.

Comment: So, something like in Unity?

Comment: Yeah, kinda similar to that, but the script will not have to be attached to an object

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What are you trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution from [c# get all inherited classes of a class](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/c%23+get+all+inherited+classes+of+a+class) article, which finds everything derived from a class, then I iterated through the list that creates and instanced them, which works now

```
// Finds all classes derived from the BaseScript class
var scripts = System.Reflection
                    .Assembly
                    .GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(TheType => TheType.IsClass
                                   && TheType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseScript)));

// Adds all of those classes to list
foreach (Type scr in scripts.ToList())
{
    BaseScripts.Add((BaseScript)Activator.CreateInstance(comp));
}

// Executes the start method in all BaseScripts
foreach (BaseScript scr in BaseScripts.ToList())
{
    scr.Start();
}
```

Comment: ok, if you now would edit your question post and add all the information from your comment, then this answer might even befound and be useful for future readers. Up to now this is a solution to a very unclear question. May be now it will be easier for you to formulate what your problem was, since you found already a solution to it